# Only accept positive integers using while loop or any other

Tags: java, algorithm, java.util.scanner, user-input, do-while

My program currently rejects any inputs other than an integer, but I'm trying to take it one step further and have it accept only positive integers. How would i accomplish this. I tried creating another boolean and calling it numisGreat and another do-while loop for this part, but I'm cant seem to get it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TandE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int firstN = 0;
        int secondN = 0;
        boolean isNumber = false;
        boolean numisGreat = false;

        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        do {
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                firstN = input.nextInt();
                isNumber = true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
                isNumber = false;
                input.next();
            }

        } while (!(isNumber));

        System.out.print("Enter another positive integer: ");
        do {
            if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                secondN = input.nextInt();
                isNumber = true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
                isNumber = false;
                input.next();
            } 

        } while (!(isNumber));

        System.out.println("The GCD of " + firstN + " and " + secondN + " is " + gCd(firstN, secondN));

    }

    public static int gCd(int firstN, int secondN) {
        if (secondN == 0) {
            return firstN;
        } else
            return gCd(secondN, firstN % secondN);
    }

}
```

Comment: hasNextInt() does not check for positive or negative. What exactly do you think this 'll do?

Comment: hasNextInt() is to check is the user entered an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a condition that tests if the input number is positive :

```
boolean isPosNumber = false;
do {
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        firstN = input.nextInt();
        if (firstN > 0) {
            isPosNumber = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You entered a non-positive number, try again: ");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
        isPosNumber = false;
        input.next();
    }

} while (!isPosNumber);
```

Comment: Eran: you have an issue with your { }. the else block is not linked to the firstN > 0

Comment: @Stultuske Oh, I see. The code can be improved to prompt the user when a negative number is input.

Comment: I just ran it and when you input any integer and hit enter, nothing gets shown back. You have to enter another integer and then it says "Enter another positive integer. Also if you enter a positive and then a negative, it still accepts the negative.

Comment: @EdtheBig I thought you'd figure out that the loop that gets the second input number must be changed the same way as the first loop in order to accept only positive numbers.

Comment: @Eran Your answer just helped me with my HW I been struggling with. Thanks.